# How to draw a set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $a<0,\nu>0 $ be two fixed parameter such that  $a\nu\in ]-\infty,0[$.

I want to draw the following set

\begin{align*}
\left\{\sqrt{1-a\nu}+\sqrt{1-a\nu}\;(k_1+k_2)+(k_2-k_1),\;k_1,k_2\in\mathbb{N}\right\}
\end{align*}

Can you pease help me to do so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Assume $k_2=0$. Then you get a set

$$
\left\{\sqrt{1-a\nu}+(\sqrt{1-a\nu}-1)k_1,\;\;k_1 \in\mathbb{N}\right\}
$$

Each time when $k_2$ is incremented, the extra points are obtained via shift by $\sqrt{1-a\nu}+1$

Comment: i want to draw that set using latex, and i don't know how, can you please help me?